# WP_Query - meta fields numeric

Tags: wp-query

I'm having trouble with the code below.  Attempting to do a query against meta data stored with the posts, in the mls post type.  I think I know what the issue is, but not how to fix it.  I am guessing it has something to do with the value being stored as a string.  I've searched and found other people confused about this, but not a solution.  Here are two examples I've attempted with no luck.

```
<?php $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'mls',
        'meta_query' => array(
            relation => 'AND', 
            array(
                'key' => '_city',
                'value' => 'Clarkson',
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_price',
                'value' => '200000',                    
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '>='
            )
            //array(
            //  'key' => '_price',
            //  'value' => array( 200000, 1000000 ),
            //  'type' => 'numeric',
            //  'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
            //)
        )
    ); ?>
```

Comment: There is nothing *technically* wrong with the above code snippet. Those are valid arguments for `WP_Query()` - you either have to share more of the queries code, or your values are simply not represented in the database.

Comment: @JohannesPille - You are absolutely correct.  After beating my head against the wall.  Your comment sent me to look again to verify.  I installed the debug admin plugin.  Along with the add-on that shows meta data.  Some of the data was normalized and renamed.  There was indeed a _city field.  However, the _price field was actually named __price... and there was a __city that I should have been using ( notice they have two under scores, and that was my issue.  THANKS!!! )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but you are missing query relation...

```
<?php $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'mls',
        'meta_query' => array(
            relation => 'AND', 
            array(
                'key' => '_city',
                'value' => 'Clarkson',
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_price',
                'value' => '200000',                    
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '>='
            )
            //array(
            //  'key' => '_price',
            //  'value' => array( 200000, 1000000 ),
            //  'type' => 'numeric',
            //  'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
            //)
        )
    ); ?>
```

Comment: You are right.  I've since tested that as well, but still no joy.  However, I can tell you that by changing the relation to "OR" I was able to get it to return posts.  Which does narrow the issue down to something the key _price portion of the query.

Comment: Try with "OR" and compare => 'BETWEEN' for a case key value is not strictly set to 200000.

Comment: Trying with OR and the BETWEEN example above only returns posts that match the _city of Clarkson.  Still nothing returning based on the _price key.

Comment: `AND` is the default relation - there is no need to set it explicitly (see [/wp-includes/meta.php, line 647](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L638)).